If I have a 200amp main breaker can I upgrade a 20amp braker to a 50 without having to rewire?
The main breaker is 200amp with several 100amp brakers and one 20amp that runs the receptacle on the side of the box.  Id like to upgrade the receptacle and 20amp to a 50amp for my RV but I don't know if I need to rewire?  Wouldn't a 200amp box be using wire for higher ampage  or will this be something I'll need to also replace?

To start with, a 50A RV connection is a four wire connection, and a typical 20A connection is three wire.  So yes, you will need to replace the wires.

No.  A 20 amp breaker will use small 12 gauge wire size.
50 amps will cook/burn/cause fire on that small gauge wire.
Breakers protect the wires from burning, so a bigger breaker must also have bigger wires.
You will need to rewire from the breaker to the RV.
It is kind of concerning for safety that you have several 100 amp breakers in a 200 amp panel.  One 100 amp maybe, but not that common.  You might want an expert to check that panel.
If by rewire, you meant the whole panel, probably not, but you only have 200 amps total to use.  Several 100 amp breakers should not be in it either, so something seems fishy.  Possible a major building fire soon fishy.

I’m guessing the 100A breakers serve sub panels. So maybe not so much ‘house fire’ if that’s the case. OP still needs a real electrician to set eyes and do a load calc to see if rv outlet is feasible.

@AloysiusDefenestrate   Most people read/use several as more than two.   So right that real electrician is needed on site.

No.
The purpose of the breakers is to protect the house wiring. If you have a 20 amp breaker, the circuit will have been wired for 20 amps. Running 50 amps through it would risk a fire, unless you are willing to rip out the existing wiring and put in sufficiently thick conductors.
If you need a circuit for the rv, put in a new circuit for the RV.
